# How to: set the selected "drop down list" value at run time

Tags: java

The pasted below code i am using to create dropdown list and java script for doing some stuffs

```
<td>
  <select id="currentCustomer" onchange="showSelectedCustomer(this)">
  <c:forEach var="Customer" items="${listCustomer}" >
      <option value="<c:out value="${Customer}" />"><c:out value="${Customer}" />
      </option>
 </c:forEach>
  </select>
</td>

function showSelectedCustomer(dropdown) {
var selectedCustomer = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
var currentCustomer = document.getElementById('currentCustomer');

 var context = document.forms[0].context.value;
document.forms[0].mode.value = "UPDATE";
document.forms[0].custName.value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
document.forms[0].action=context+"/updateReportDetail.do";
document.forms[0].method="POST";
document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

My problem is
 how to set the onselected value dynamically in drop down list.

Let me explain briefly here,

Initially at the time of logging application the landing "x.JSP" page will display drop down list with multiple customer names with first customer name as selected one by default.
If i select other customer name in drop down list i am calling Javascript[onchage event] to submitting to form and to do some other stuffs in DAO java class for the selected customer and returning back to "x.JSP" page.

Now the thing is i need to set the latest customer name [ie..the customer i processed in DAO java class] as  onselected one in the drop down list.

Help me guys.Thanks for your effort in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your forEach loop, check if the Customer in your current iteration is the one that matches your predetermined choice.  You don't give any indication of how you're choosing the "right" customer to be selected when the page loads, so I'll use some pseudo-code for that.

```
<c:forEach var="Customer" items="${listCustomer}" >
   <%  String selected = "";  
       if (customer.equals(predeterminedCustomerToBeSelected)) {
           selected = "selected"; }
   %>
      <option value="<c:out value="${Customer}" />" <%=selected%>><c:out value="${Customer}" />
      </option>
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: . yes,i dont have any idea how to print the previous selected customer as selected one now,thats what i am asking .

Comment: Well you need to store it somewhere.  Store it in the session, write it as a cookie, do something so you can retrieve it later.

Comment: I use jQuery for everything client side, so in jQuery it would be something like (using the jquery.cookie.js plugin)

$(document).ready({
    var preselected = $.cookie("mySelection");
    $("#selectCustomer").val(preselected);
});

The syntax might be off, but should be easy to fix.